# Narrowing XPath in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

Trying to click a link which can be duplicated elsewhere on the page randomly so I'm narrowing it down based on other content in that table.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(Driver.page_source, "html5lib")
for EachTable in soup.find_all("tr"):
  if data_check in EachTable.get_text():
    links = Driver.find_elements_by_xpath("span[contains(.,'%s')]" % data_to_check)
```

My XPath isn't great. I know that //span etc... will target everything on that page and that works but when there's a duplicate I need to narrow it down to that part of EachTable.

I tried:

```
links = EachTable.find_elements_by_xpath("span[contains(.,'%s')]" % data_to_check)
```

But that was a long shot and obviously it didn't support find_elements_by_xpath.

So if I can narrow it down and data_to_check is in EachTable is it possible to limit my Xpath to that table this way or will I have to change the overall Xpath to look at the full table to see if it contains the data_to_check instead?

Is it possible to do Xpath something like this?

```
links = Driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[contains(.,'%s')]" % tr_data and //span[contains(.,'%s')]" % span_data)
```

I'm not sure of the syntax but that would get the same result and probably be more efficient.

Comment: Have you looked at http://scrapy.org/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: Is it possible to do Xpath something like this?

```
//tr[contains(.,'%s')]" % tr_data and //span[contains(.,'%s')]" % span_data)
```

Should be something like:

```
"//tr[contains(.,'%s')]//span[contains(.,'%s')]" % (tr_data,span_data)
```

This will look for all span with span_data inside of tr with tr_data.

Comment: This was perfect. Much appreciated!